# voice recognition api "bing" in python is very slow

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, voice-recognition, bing-api

I am using the following code to use voice recognition in python

```
import speech_recognition as sr

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
print("Say something!")
audio = r.listen(source)
print(type(audio))


BING_KEY = 'KEY'  # Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition API keys 32-character lowercase hexadecimal strings
try:
    print(type(r.recognize_bing(audio, key=BING_KEY)))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

But it is very slow, it even lags for 20 seconds! which is very slow, can you recommend any REAL TIME voice recognition api in python? or any suggested modifications for that code

Answer (score 2):

I use Bing Speech API but I dont use a client library like you. I use the REST api. I get audio live using PyAudio and when I detect that the noise level has gone up I start recording the sound to a wav file then when its finished I send to the audio data to the endpoint that the api documentation gives you. It gives me a response rather quickly, at most 3 seconds but it kinda depends on your wifi speed. My method is more involved than yours but it is worth it.

[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/getstarted/getstartedrest) is a link to the documentation. They use C# in their examples but since it is an online api, if you send the right information in the headers and such it should still work.

Comment: I am using python, so if you have a code sample for the REST api in python I will be very grateful